# Proving that the first Weyl Algebra is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, noncommutative-algebra, algebras

The first Weyl algebra over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is defined to be the set  $A_1 = {\{\sum_{i = 0}^{n} f_i(x) \delta^i : f_i(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x] }\}$. So it is the set of all linear differential operators with polynomial coefficients. $\delta$ is an operator meaning differentiation, and, $x$ is an operator meaning multiplication by $x$. As operators, the following relation holds; $(\delta \cdot x) = (1 + x \cdot \delta)$.

Now, I've been reading a proof of the simplicity of the above algebra, but I don't understand it.

Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of $A_1$. Choose a non-zero element $a \in I$. Hence, we may write $a = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} f_i(x)\delta^i$. Choose an $a$ such that $n$ is minimal. Then,the following is clearly in $I$ $$ -xa +ax  = \sum_{i=0}^{n} f_i(x)(-x\delta^i + \delta^ix) = \sum_{i=o}^nf_i(x)(i\delta^{i-1}) = nf_n(x)\delta^{n-1} + ... \neq 0 - (1)$$

This contradicts the minimality of $n$ and hence $n = 0$. Hence, $a = \sum_{j=0}^m\lambda_ix^i$, $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}$, with $\lambda_m \neq 0$.

Now, note that the following expression is in $I$ ; $$\delta a - a \delta = \sum_{j = 0}^m \lambda_i i x^{i-1} - (2)$$

Repeating this $m$ times we see that $\lambda_m(m!) \in I$, thus $1 \in I$, thus $I = A_1$ and we're done.

I don't understand how $(1)$ works? How are they getting these expressions? Does $ax$ mean applying the linear transformation $a$ to the polynomial $x$, or is it multiplication by $x$?

Also, going from $\sum_{i=0}^{n} f_i(x)(-x\delta^i + \delta^ix)$ to $\sum_{i=o}^nf_i(x)(i\delta^{i-1})$ seems like the $\delta^i$ has been differentiated by the $x$? How does this work?

How is it clear that the expression is nonzero? How is the minimality of $n$ contradicted here?

Also, in $(2)$, again, I'm unsure of how they've got that expression?

Sorry for all of the questions, I'm just really struggling to grasp this proof!

Answer (score 2):

For any ring, define the *commutator* by
$$[A,B]\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}AB-BA\text{.}$$
In any ring, this map is bilinear over the center and satisfies the *product rule*
$$\begin{align}[D,FG]&=[D,F]G+F[D,G]\\
[AB,X]&=A[B,X]+[A,X]B\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Now, the defining relation for the Weyl algebra is
$$[\delta,x]=1\text{.}$$
From this relation and the product rules above, we may *prove* that, for any univariate polynomials $f,a$, we have
$$\begin{align}
[\delta,f(x)]&=f'(x) &[a(\delta),x]&=a'(\delta)\\
[\delta,a(\delta)]&=0 &[f(x),x]&=0\text{.}
\end{align}$$

And now for the essence of the proof. Write $\mathsf{X},\mathsf{\Delta}$ for the $\mathbb{C}$-linear maps on $A_1$
$$\begin{align}\mathsf{X}a&\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}[a,x]\\
\mathsf{\Delta}a&\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}[\delta,a]\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Any nonzero element $a$ of $A_1$ may be written as
$$a=\sum_{i=0}^nf_i(x)\delta^i$$
where
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^m\lambda_jx^j$$
and where $\lambda_m\neq 0$. ($\lambda_m\neq 0$ guarantees that $n$ is the order of $a$ and that $m$ is the degree of $f$. That every nonzero element of $A_1$ has a well-defined order basically corresponds to the minimality and non-zeroness part of your exposition.)

Then from the identities for the commutator above we have
$$\tfrac{1}{m!n!\lambda_m}\mathsf{\Delta}^m\mathsf{X}^na=1\text{;}$$
Thus every two-sided ideal containing a nonzero element $a$ contains $1$.

Comment: So $ [\delta, f(x)] = \delta f(x) - f(x)\delta$. I know $\delta f(x) = f’(x)$, but, how do I deal with the term $f(x) \delta$?

Comment: As members of the Weyl algebra, the product of $\delta$ and $f(x)$ is *not* $f'(x)$. To calculate that commutator, use the defining relation and product rule for the commutator to show that $[\delta,x^n]=n x^{n-1}$ by induction on $n$, and then invoke linearity over the center.

Comment: I thought $\delta$ acted on $\mathbb{C}[x]$ with the action $\delta$ defined as $\delta \cdot (f(x)) = f’(x)$?

Comment: Can I not look at the element $\delta f(x) - f(x) \delta$ and see how it acts on an element of $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Let $\cdot$ denote the action. Then $(\delta f(x) - f(x) \delta) \cdot g(x) =( \delta f(x)) \cdot g(x)  - (f(x)\delta)\cdot g(x)) = \delta \cdot (f(x)g(x)) - f(x)g’(x) = f’(x)g(x)$by the product rule. So, as operators, $\delta f(x) - f(x) \delta = f’(x)?$

Comment: You can, but then you need to have already proven that $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a faithful left $A_1$-module, so that two elements of $A_1$ are equal iff they induce equal operations on $\mathbb{C}[x]$